# bash script to have a postgres DB in a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

I'm having trouble in creating a Postgres DB using this bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

docker pull postgres
docker run --name coverage-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 -d postgres 

export CONTAINER_ID=$(sudo docker ps -a | grep coverage-postgres | head -c12)

sleep 2s
sudo docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres -c "create user coverage_user with password 'password';"
sleep 0.5
sudo docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres -c "create database coverage owner coverage_user;"
sleep 0.5
sudo docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres -c "grant all privileges on database coverage to coverage_user;"
sleep 0.5
sudo docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres -c "\c coverage coverage_user" # it seems useless...
sleep 0.5
sudo docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres -c "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS postal_codes (id,...;"
sleep 0.5
sudo docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres -c "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ... ;"

# exit from container
exit
# restart container
docker start $CONTAINER_ID
```

In particular, the database is created, the user is created, the table is created but... **it's not in the coverage db but in postgres db**.

I've tried to add *"CREATE TABLE coverage.postal_codes"* but coverage is a db and not a schema and it didn't work.

I've tried to use: **psql -U coverage_user** but the system tells me that **database coverage_user doesn't exist**.

So of course I thought "I have to specify the database of course!". Then I've tried to use: **psql -U coverage** as the name of the database but this time, the system makes fun of me and, changing its mind, tells me that the **role coverage doesn't exists**.

I tried a workaround: within the command -c "\c coverage coverage_user" I concatenated the other commands this way:

```
-c "\c coverage coverage_user; CREATE TABLE...; CREATE UNIQUE INDEX...;"
```

but, of course, neither this worked at all.

I make a premise: I know there are other ways to do this but I would like to understand what I am missing with these specific commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
#! /bin/bash

docker pull postgres
docker run --name coverage-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 -d postgres 

export CONTAINER_ID=$(sudo docker ps -a | grep coverage-postgres | head -c12)

sleep 2s
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres -c "create user coverage_user with password 'password';"
sleep 0.5
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres -c "create database coverage owner coverage_user;"
sleep 0.5
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres -c "grant all privileges on database coverage to coverage_user;"
sleep 0.5
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID psql -U coverage_user -c "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS postal_codes (id int)" coverage
```

#### Explanation

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-psql.html

> psql [option...] [dbname [username]]

Just add `dbname` after options. And change user as `-U` option. You can pass `dbname` also as an rgument `-d`